# How to render my apex chart after ajax call is complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, apexcharts, webapi

I'm using apex dynamic chart [Apex dynamic chart](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/column-charts/dynamic-loaded-chart/)

And I'm getting stuck on the ajax call & chart render section. There's Country Bar chart. When I clicked on a country bar, then selected countryID is passed to the updateStacked100Chart function(which calls ajax webapi with countryID ) below to get region data for that country in a stacked100 apex chart. An empty stacked100 apex Chart is rendered first before the ajax call is completed. How do I fix this?

```
 //sourceChart=CountryBarChart,destChartIDToUpdate=Stacked100RegionYearChart(Chart to be updated based on country bar selected)
        function updateStacked100Chart(sourceChart, destChartIDToUpdate) {
            var series = [];
            var seriesIndex = 0;
           var categorySource = [];
            var color = ['#008FFB', '#00E396', '#FEB019', '#FF4560', '#775DD0', '#00D9E9', '#FF66C3'];

            if (sourceChart.w.globals.selectedDataPoints[0]) {
                //Get selected country bar in CountryBarChart
                var selectedPoints = sourceChart.w.globals.selectedDataPoints;
                for (var i = 0; i < selectedPoints[seriesIndex].length; i++) {
                    var selectedIndex = selectedPoints[seriesIndex][i];
                    var selectedCountry = sourceChart.w.globals.labels[selectedIndex];
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://localhost:51604/api/Sales/GetSalesByRegion",
                        type: "Get",
                        dataType: "json",
                        cache: false,
                        data: {

                            "CountryId": selectedCountry,
                            "page": 0,
                            "limit": 0
                        },

                        success: function (data) {
                            // Prepare series &  xaxis category data for stacked100 region chart
                            $.each(data.salesByRegQuery, function (index, item) {
                                series.push(
                                    {
                                        name: item.EnglishProductCategoryName,
                                        data: item.Total_Margin
                                    });
                                categorySource.push(item.CalendarYear);

                            });


                        },
                        complete: function (data) {

                        },

                        error: function (data) {

                        }
                    });
                }

                //These lines of codes below get executed first before ajax call is completed.
                if (series.length === 0) series = [{
                    data: []
                }];
                //So, region stacked100 apex chart source data for series and xaxis aren't updated
                return ApexCharts.exec(destChartIDToUpdate, 'updateOptions', {
                    series: series,
                    xaxis: categorySource,
                    colors: color,
                    fill: {
                        colors: color
                    }
                });
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens because Ajax is Async by default. You should call render in "Success" section. So you'll be sure, that "series" array has data.

Comment: This was my problem for a hours now!!!! great piece of information. I was doing an ajax call wiithin a function. by setting  `async:false`, I was able to run the `return` the global variable set by the ajax. Great stuff!